# MUI - StyledComponents, unable to append className to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I've been trying to append a className to my extended mui `<TextField />` component however some really strange things are happening that I can't seem to figure out:

1. if *no* classNames are provided to instances of my component, "colorsOverride" will appear on the dom and behave as expected.
2. if *one or more* classNames are provided to an instance of my component, the provided classNames will appear **but "colorsOverride" will not** appear in the `classNames` attribute.

I've tried a bunch of things and, by all accounts the string-template concat should work below as there are plenty of examples of it online, yet ... it doesn't.

Am I missing something obvious here? this is really strange and i'm stumped.

```js
const StyledTextField = ({
  variant = 'standard',
  colorsOverride = false,
  ...props
}: IStyledTextField): JSX.Element => {
  // ? https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html
  if (colorsOverride) {
    const className = `${props.className} colorsOverride`;
    return (
      <CustomTextField className={className} variant={variant} {...props} />
    );
  }
  return <CustomTextField variant={variant} {...props} />;
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings/errors?

Comment: It's probably because you are already spreading the props and they contain a className. So you get className twice, once from className={className} and once from {...props} which contains just the class names and not the colorsOverride. That's my first guess. Try using a different props name, instead of classNames.

Comment: You might even try placing the className prop after the {...props} like this: <CustomTextField variant={variant} {...props} className={className} /> and see if it retains the last className definition.

Comment: Hello, I wasn't getting errors. Thanks for the suggestions, ill give them a try